# R - error installing source packages: unknown timezone GMT

Tags: r, r-package

On my colleague's computer, I can't install R packages from source. I always get an error: `Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT'`. On my own computer, I have no problems at all.

In researching this, I've seen people fix timezone issues which give the same warning by using `Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/London")`. That doesn't work here. I also found an old post suggesting adding `--without-internal-tzcode` to `build_opts`, but it looks like that option isn't recognised (anymore?).

This is driving me crazy, any ideas?

Here's a full example of what happens:

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ="Europe/London")
> devtools::install_github("DanielGardiner/EpiFunc")
Downloading GitHub repo DanielGardiner/EpiFunc@master
√  checking for file 'C:\.../DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'EpiFunc':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
   Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT'
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'EpiFunc_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'EpiFunc' ...
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : 
  (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'GMT'
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'EpiFunc'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5/EpiFunc'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error: Failed to install 'EpiFunc' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/.../EpiFunc_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is on Windows 10, with R version 3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and managed to get rid of the `(converted from warning)` by calling `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS"=TRUE)` prior to calling `remotes::install_github`.

If it is of any use to anyone, it turns out that I have no `R.h` file in the `R_home/include` directory. I am not sure if this is related to the unknown time zone issue but this still caused me to not be able to install the package.

The question here seems related to [this Github issue](https://github.com/PaoloBnn/Retip/issues/6#issue-769147795).